# Codeigniter routing issues displaying two classname in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to display two class name in a url?
For instance i have two class: Category and Gallery.

I want to display it in url as ...`category/gallery/2` ?

Comment: what is that you want!!!!!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes, you can route anything to anything. No, you can't call two different controllers based solely on the route. You would have to call one from the other, and CodeIgniter makes it annoying to even try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm.. as far as I know, you cannot have 2 classes like that. But what you can do is have a class called 'Category' and inside that a function called "Gallery". And inside that you can get the value 2 by using uri segment.

I have attached the below code for reference.

```
class category extends Controller {

    //php 5 constructor
    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    //php 4 constructor
    function category() {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function gallery() {
        $galleryId = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if($galleryId==2){
            //<statements>
        }
    }
```

}

category/gallery/2 will take you to .

Thanks

Comment: i was wondering it only because i want to manage code in two class as category and gallery.. however its seems not possible in CI... so i guess... i have to use it your way(the only easiest way for now).. thank you.